# Regular expression: Need help finding matches within a file

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression and I am trying to match the following:

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Access-List Machine1
  IP address 000.000.000.1
  IP address 000.000.000.2
  IP address 000.000.000.3
Access-List Machine2
  IP address 000.000.000.1
  IP address 000.000.000.2
  IP address 000.000.000.3
```

I want to use regular expression to grab the header Access-List and the IP address 000.000.000.2 for both Machine1 and Machine2

So far I have got

```
r"Access-List (.*)\n .* (000.000.000.2)*"
```

I get no matches however if I put the IP address 000.000.000.1 then I get both matches

Would love some help

Comment: Is it Python? Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Do you want to match all machines that have a particular IP in their list?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried contains a single newline. If that would match the first line that contains an ip number, it will only match the number in that line and if you change that to 1 it will find the 2 ip numbers.

The current pattern has a 2 at the end, so the match will stop right before it can match the second capturing group as a whole which contains `000.000.000.1`

One way to get your desired values is to repeat the lines that do not contain your ip address until to arrive at the line that does using a negative lookahead.

Note to escape the dots `\.` to match them literally.

```
^Access-List (.*)(?:\r?\n(?!.* 000\.000\.000\.2).*)*\r?\n.*(000\.000\.000\.2)
```

- `^` Start of the string (If it starts there)
- `Access-List (.*)` Match `Access-List`, space and capture group 1 with the content till the end of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!.* 000\.000\.000\.2).*`  Match the whole line if it does not contain the ip ending on 2
- `)*` Close non capturing group, repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n.*(000\.000\.000\.2)` Capture the ip in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dn01a6/1)